# Windows 8.1 changed msconfig to boot to safe mode and now it won't boot

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, msconfig

I was trying to get my computer to boot to safe mode so I could delete all AVG virus scan related files. I followed instructions online where they said to change the msconfig.exe setting in the boot tab to boot in safe mode.

After making the change and restarted, but the computer won't boot to any screen at all. The F8 during the boot is unresponsive. I cannot even get it to boot to my Windows 8.1 DVD.

How can I revert the msconfig change I made so I can boot successfully? Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Bootrec.exe to reset your Windows boot configuration? Whatever has been broken during the failed safe boot sequence, it will be put to the default normal Windows booting. Here you can find more details on this: [Windows 8.1 changed msconfig to boot to safe mode and now it won't boot](https://superuser.com/questions/1171860/windows-8-1-changed-msconfig-to-boot-to-safe-mode-and-now-it-wont-boot) .

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the box for "Make all boot settings permanent" was unchecked

And when you boot with F8 try to select Last Known good configuration

if your pc cannot boot to a DVD with unresponsiveness it means you have another problem due perhaps to a faulty hardware like hard drive.